# '-alias' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, windows, shell, android-studio, command

I am trying to run this command on terminal -
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>

after putting keyname and key path I am getting this error -
'-alias' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command should be on one line without the backslash:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it then says "'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @WebDevelopmentLabs that means that `keytool` is not on your path. You can work around it by supplying the full path to the keytool executable (something like `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\keytool.exe"`

Answer (score 4):

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

After that

**Password: android**

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore"
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

**I used this code and it works for me you can also try it for fast resolution or keep on trying the formal thank you**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore 
-alias androiddebugkey
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Whether you use either of the code it will still work I have been stocked with that issue but when I use the code I was able to generate the key

Answer (score 0):

2023 solution..

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin
```

and

```
keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

thats all..